# opengeo Error: Could not create tool plugin with ptype: gxp_queryform

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I'm trying to develop the tutorial of opengeo-suite sdk, but when I try to add a queryform to my app, firebug throws this exception:

> Error: Could not create tool plugin with ptype: gxp_queryform
>   I've tryed to perform a query form and i used this code

- @require plugins/QueryForm.js

  {
  ptype: "gxp_featuremanager",
  id: "states_manager",
  maxFeatures: 20
   },{
          ptype: "gxp_queryform",
          featureManager: "states_manager",
          outputConfig: {
              title: "Query",
              width: 320
          },
          actionTarget: ["featuregrid.bbar"],
          appendActions: false
      }

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you give us an example?  What code caused that error to be thrown?

Comment: Is this related to [your other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62072/grid-not-displaying-content)?  Please clearly communicate what you've done and what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry about the poor information I've provided. I've put the code now.
The example is the same, but I've solved the another problem, this one is new problem, it's a problem with QueryForm

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the FeatureManager is not bound to a layer.

Either specify the `layer` or `autoSetLayer` property in your FeatureManager, like:

```
/*
 * @require plugins/FeatureManager.js
 * @require plugins/QueryForm.js
 */

{
  ptype: "gxp_featuremanager",
  id: "states_manager",
  maxFeatures: 20,
  layer: { 
    source: "local",
    name: "usa:states"
  }
}, {
  ptype: "gxp_queryform",
  featureManager: "states_manager",
  outputConfig: {
    title: "Query",
    width: 320
  },
  actionTarget: "featuregrid.bbar"
}
```